# R data frame issue - non-numeric headers

Tags: r, dataframe

This is definitely a rookie question but I'm not finding an answer for this (maybe because of my wording) so here goes:

I'm reading a data frame into R studio (csv file) that has 24 columns with headers. There are only numbers in these columns (they're essentially concentrations of several chemicals). It's called all. I need to use them as numeric vectors. When I read them in and type

```
is.numeric(all[,1])
```

I get

```
TRUE
```

When I type

```
is.numeric(all[1])
```

I get

```
FALSE
```

I think this is because R interprets the header as a factor. I also tried reading in a table without headers and with `headers=FALSE`, but R renames it to V1, V2 etc so the result ends up being the same.

I need to work with functions where I invoke something like `all[2:24]`. How can I go about to make R either "not see" the header or remove it altogether?

Thanks for the answers!

PS: the dataframe I am using (without headers - if it had headers, it would just have names instead of V1, V2, etc) is something like this:

[image: data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subset from the first column, not the first row.

```
all[,1]) #subset first column
```

The following is subset of first row

```
all[1,]) #subset first row (headers of df not included)
```

To give columnames

```
colnames(all) <- c("col1","col2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. You have a data.frame and `all[1]` does list subsetting, which results in a data.frame, which is not a vector, and not a numeric vector in particular.

You should study `help("[")` and [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).